# How do I make my wallpaper scroll on my Android?

Tags: wallpaper

To be specific, I have one page on my homescreen. How can I have just the wallpaper scrolling in the background and the icons staying still?

Comment: Just for clarification: Are you rather asking for a [live-wallpaper](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-wallpaper) (basically, an "animated wallpaper")?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://novalauncher.com/ for a great Launcher if your device does not natively support wallpaper scrolling; it's possible to force it with Nova Launcher.

I'm not sure it's possible to implement wallpaper scrolling with a single page; you could try duplicating the page and removing the transition animations to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Yeah I've figured out a loophole! I created 5 copies of the same page with the same icon in each location, then I added the "wipe" effect from Nova. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck!